# Mysql anormally slow

Tags: mysql, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I'm actually new on a project. I have to install mysql server to create local tables.
My collegues create this table within 1min. 
My computer install it within 25min.
We all have the same configuration exept that they use linux mint and I use Windows 10 with the linux kernel.

This problem is reprodutable with the other guy who came at the same moment as me with Ubuntu 18.04.

We heard that Ubuntu 18.04 decrease the CPU usages : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095623/mysql-5-7-is-working-slow-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1097401#1097401 
However, this solution didn't work for me.

Configuration :
- Windows 10 with Linux 18.04 kernel (my collegues have Linux Mint but i don't know the version)
- Mysql 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (my collegues have 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no information in your question that could be used to help you.

Comment: I actually have no idea why our computer have different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint actually uses the same core and repositories as Ubuntu. I guess they are identical (at least regarding Mysql). The problem is somewhere else.
Can you please explain what you mean 'create table within 1 min / 25 mins'? I guess it was not just CREATE TABLE ... command? Did you load some massive data into the table?
First I would recommend you to install MySQL Workbench - a nice free grafical tool for mySql management. You can get it either from Oracle ( https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ ) or from your Linux repo.
Check if you have the same 'engine' for your table (in its properties) as your colleague. InnoDB is the most common.
Then check your mySQL server setting in **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**
If you use InnoDB you can boost your performance by adding at least

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
```

in the defalt file.
This example sets in-memory buffer to 2 Gb. Use 30-50-...% of your RAM for it depending on the size of the resulting database.
You can also try

```
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

To avoid some extra OS buffering, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In my collegue computer the script is composed of drop/create/insert tables. 
It takes ~2min for him, I take 25min with same tables/data/mysql configuration. 
The data corresponding is not huge data.

We already tried the buffer pool size to 4G or the flush_method to o_direct.
But, it doesn't change anything (this configuration I tried was the link in my first post).

I also already checked the **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**. We have the same configuration. 

The only difference we saw is the version of mysql.